# GUID must be 16 bytes long

Tags: c#, overloading

I am trying to overload a method which uses a Guid as its parameter with another method that has a string as its parameter.

```
    // read a student object from the dictionary
    static public User Retrieve(Guid ID)
    {
        User user;
        // find the Guid in the Dictionary
        user = Users[ID];
        return user;
    }

    static public User Retrieve(string Email)
    {
        User user;
        Guid id;
        // find the Guid in the Dictionary
        using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
        {
            byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Email));
            id = new Guid(hash);
        }
        user = Users[id];
        return user;
    }
```

Test Results
Result Message: 
Test method SRS.CRUDUsers.UpdateStudent threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16 bytes long.

Test Method:

```
    public void UpdateStudent()
    {
        // Arrange
        Student expected = (Student)UserRepo.Retrieve("info@info.com");

        // Act
        Student actual = (Student)UserRepo.Retrieve("info@info.com");
        actual.FirstName = "Joe";
        actual.LastName = "Brown";
        actual.Birthday = new DateTime(1977, 2, 23);
        actual.DegreeSelected = 1;

        // Assert (this is only really checking the object agains itself
        // because both variables are referencing the same object).
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(actual.ID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Name, actual.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.GetType(), actual.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Birthday, actual.Birthday);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Age, actual.Age);
    }
```

It seems to be a type issue so probably something obvious.

Comment: Can you post your `Test method SRS.CRUDUsers.UpdateStudent` ?

Comment: The issue presumably is that a SHA1 hash of an email address isn't a valid Guid (it's 20 bytes vs 16 bytes for starters). Is there any reason it should be?

Comment: Please include the implementation of the `User` class.

Comment: Indeed - this seems to have nothing to do with overloading, really...

Comment: you include code that is not really relevant to the problem described, add the missing part

Comment: It sort of looks like you are trying to implement deterministic guids on the cheap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a Guid from a SHA-1 byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362225/how-can-i-generate-a-guid-from-a-sha-1-byte-array)

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of that, and yes it is deterministic guids on the cheap. Its for a last minute uni project. I am looking at it to try and understand what I am asking better myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):

> SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (**20-byte**)

Error:

> Byte array for GUID must be exactly **16 bytes long**.

So you can't just use SHA1 as Guid. You can try MD5 (it is 128) if this is not security related code.

Comment: I changed to MD5 and it still doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Correction to above that is no longer occuring its a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
new Guid(hash.Take(16).ToArray())
```

Or you can use MD5 hash, since it is a 16-byte hash

```
var md5 = MD5.Create();
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Email));
new Guid(hash);
```